# WPF forward/back button

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I would like to make back and forward button in my app in WPF (Visual Basic 2010 Express). I have six tabitems and this two buttons will be used to navigate between tabitems.

I have used following code, but it doesn't work. what am I doing wrong?

```
Public ReadOnly Property CanGoForward As Boolean
    Get
        CanGoForward = True
    End Get
End Property

Private Sub forward_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles forward.Click
    TabIdentiPodatki.goforward()
End Sub

Private Sub TabIdentiPodatki_CanGoForwardChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles forward.CanGoForwardChanged
    forward.IsEnabled = TabIdentiPodatki.cangoforward
End Sub
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at [page based navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx)?

Comment: this solved my problem:      Me.TabControl2.SelectedItem = TabIdentiPodatki